# Is manually unlocking associated mutex of a RAII wrapper (like st::unique_lock) always a UB?

Tags: c++, synchronization

I wonder if manually unlocking a mutex associated with a RAII wrapper is always a UB. For example, is it ok **if we lock it again before RAII wrapper destroys** like this:

```
int i = 0;
std::mutex mx_;

void foo() {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx_);
        i++;
        mx_.unlock();
        mx_.lock();
        i++;
    }
}
```

The reason for my question is that I'm trying to write a small RAII wrapper that upgrades a shared lock to a exclusive lock for a `std::shared_mutex` and I need to manually lock/unlock `std::shared_mutex` that is associated with other locks and I wonder if it is UB. Here is my `upgrade_lock` class:

```
template<typename Mutex>
class upgrade_lock {
public:
    using mutex_type = Mutex;

    explicit upgrade_lock(mutex_type& mx) : mxp_(&mx) {
        mxp_->unlock_shared();
        mxp_->lock();
    }

    ~upgrade_lock() {
        mxp_->unlock();
        mxp_->lock_shared();
    }

    upgrade_lock(const upgrade_lock&) = delete;
    upgrade_lock& operator=(const upgrade_lock&) = delete;

private:
    mutex_type* mxp_ = nullptr;
};
```

I'm assumed that this class is only used when shared lock is acquired by a thread. And about why unlock/lock pairs is not guarded by another mutex, I think it is not necessary really. I can use this class like this now:

```
int i = 0;
std::shared_mutex mx_;

void goo() {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lk(mx_);
        if (i > 5000) {
            upgrade_lock<std::shared_mutex> lk2(mx_);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes unlock a lock is good (why it have that function otherwise?)

Comment: @appleapple my question is related to when a mutex is associated with a RAII wrapper like `std::unique_lock`. Because in that case, if I **only** unlock mutex manually, it will lead to UB.

Comment: Oh I see, you unlock the underlying mutex, not the lock.

Comment: I think it may be better to pass the `shared_lock` directly.

Comment: @appleapple it will not be possible, because I need access to both lock/unlock and lock_shared/unlock_shared of the `shared_mutex` and you cannot lock/unlock using `shared_lock`.

Comment: you can access the mutex from `shared_lock` though..

Comment: I think it's not UB (to operate on raw mutex) if you pair it correctly btw.

Comment: why do you think it is UB? Its not an issue that you unlock and lock it again. The issue does arise when the RAII lock tries to unlock the mutex and the mutex isnt locked by the current thread. Thats not the case in your exampel

Comment: There might be a problem in the first code if `mx_.lock()` throws an exception.

Comment: @DanielLangr same problem happens for my `upgrade_lock` too, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's UB if you pair it correctly (and no exception occur as @
DanielLangr said, which would try to unlock a already unlocked mutex)

---

You can pass the lock directly though.

```
template<typename lock_type>
class upgrade_lock {
public:
    upgrade_lock(lock_type& src_lock):lock(&src_lock){
        lock->unlock_shared();
        lock->mutex()->lock();
    }

    ~upgrade_lock() {
        lock->mutex()->unlock();
        lock->lock_shared();
    }

    upgrade_lock(const upgrade_lock&) = delete;
    upgrade_lock& operator=(const upgrade_lock&) = delete;

private:
    lock_type* lock;
};
```

(code not tested)